# Transformar valores duplicados em 0 mantendo um elemento no R com condicionais

Tags: r

Suponha que exista uma base de dados em que:

```
x    y     z
a  2015  122.4
a  2015  122.4
b  2016  200.5
a  2014  300.6
c  2016  80.1
```

O que estava querendo saber é com fazer uma programação no R que transforma os valores repetidos de z de cada grupo x e y em 0, mantendo um valor de z, sendo o resultado final como:

```
x    y     z
a  2015  122.4
a  2015    0
b  2016  200.5
a  2014  300.6
c  2016  80.1
```

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja a função `duplicated`.

```
dados$z[duplicated(dados$z)] <- 0
dados
  x    y     z
1 a 2015 122.4
2 a 2015   0.0
3 b 2016 200.5
4 a 2014 300.6
5 c 2016  80.1
```

Se quiser manter a base original, faça uma cópia previamente e modifique a cópia, `dados2 <- dados`, seguido do código acima (com `dados2`).

**Dados:**

```
dados <-
structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), y = c(2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2014L, 
2016L), z = c(122.4, 0, 200.5, 300.6, 80.1)), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

**EDIÇÃO.**

Depois de ver a resposta do Rafael Cunha reparei que tinha falhado um ponto fundamental da pergunta, que os valores repetidos ou duplicados devem ser agrupados pelas colunas `x` e `y`. A seguinte resposta dá conta desse requerimento do OP.

```
dados$z <- ave(dados$z, dados$x, dados$y, FUN = function(.z)
                ifelse(duplicated(.z), 0, .z))
```

Answer (score 4):

Segue código, utilizando o pacote `dplyr`. Nesse caso, levo em consideração o agrupamento de `x` e `y`

```
library(dplyr)
dados <-
  structure(list(
    x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), 
                  .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    y = c(2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2014L, 2016L), 
    z = c(122.4, 122.4, 200.5, 300.6, 80.1)), 
    .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

dados %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  transmute(z = ifelse(duplicated(z), 0, z))
```